# Creating Dynamic matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, create-table

I have a problem with defining some matrices in MATLAB. I get three numbers `x`,`y`,`z` as an input from user, then I want to create `y-1` empty matrices. For example consider `x = 3`, `y = 4`, and `z = 2`. The required `y-1` matrices `M1`, `M2`, and `M3` are:

```
size(M1) = [3,4] ~ [x,y]

size(M2) = [4,4] ~ [y,y]

size(M3) = [4,2] ~ [y,z]
```

The parameters `x`,`y` are not known before running the program. If `y` was 5, the matrices were:

```
size(M1) = [3,5] ~ [x,y]

size(M2) = [5,5] ~ [y,y]

size(M3) = [5,5] ~ [y,y]

size(M4) = [5,2] ~ [y,z]
```

Indeed the main problem is that the number of matrices is an input. 
Please guide me on how I can create a function loop to define this matrices.

Comment: Empty in MATLAB would be `A=[]`, a zero matrix (e.g. `A = zeros(3)') still has some size.

Comment: @Jubobs,
zero or one, or any other initial value is not important since the values will revised in the algorithm. 
Problem is that the number of matrices is an input.

Comment: You'll want to do this in a cell-class for sure. `bsxfun` and `cellfun` however cannot handle `zeros`. I'll keep digging.

Comment: If the number of variable is an input, you have to use a [`cell array`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), which will still have the benefit of matrix style indexing, or a [`structure`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html), which is convenient when you need (or prefer) to _name_ your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X = input('Enter X please: '); 
Y = input('Enter Y please: '); 
Z = input('Enter Z please: '); 
Cells={}
Cells{1}=zeros(X,Y);
for i=2:Y-1
 Cells{i}=zeros(Y,Y);   
end;
Cells{Y-1}=zeros(Y,Z);
```

Comment: I was just about to type this up. Kudoos

Comment: Probably the solution. Depending on the logic it might be simpler to use `Cells{end+1}=..` so there is no need for bookkeeping of indices.

Comment: How I can call the value of cell [i,j] in one of the matrices?

Comment: you can use of this term "Cells{prob}(i,j)" or use of new matric same as tmp=Cells{prob};

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation  .

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do this without using cells, but I strongly advice you not to, so: 
One way to do this, with each matrix being part of a cell:

```
dims = str2num(input('Type in selected x,y,z: ', 's'));

M = arrayfun(@(n) zeros(dims(n), dims(2)), [1 2*ones(1,y-1) 3], 'UniformOutput', 0)

%% In the command window:
Type in selected x,y,z: 3 4 2

M = 
    [3x4 double]    [4x4 double]    [2x4 double]
```

Note that with the [`str2num(input())`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) approach, you can input both: `[4 3 2]`, `[4, 3, 2]`, `4 3 2`, `4, 3, 2` or even `4;3;2`. It's basically impossible to make mistakes here!

The way this works is: [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) performs an operation for each elements of the vector `[1 2*ones(1,y-1) 3]`. The operation is to create a matrix of zeros, with the desired dimensions. `UniformOutput` is a parameter that must be set to `false`, or `0` if the output is something other than scalars.

To access, and make changes to any of the matrices:

When you type `M{x}`, you can think of that as the equivalent of just a matrix name, i.e. it's fine to use `()` to index the matrix, straight after the `{}`.

So, you can do:

```
M{1}(3,3) = 2;
```

which would assign the value `2` to the element `(3,3)` in matrix `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
M1 = zeros(x,y);
M2 = zeros(y,y);
M3 = zeors(z,y);
```

Simple enough. Though why `M2` and `M3` in your question are the same I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: The number of matrices is an input !,

Comment: So why are `M2` and `M3` exactly the same? You want M1 and M(end) to be `(x,y)` and `(z,y)` and everything else as `(y,y)`? I still do not understand that part.

Comment: Yes, the the first and last matrices are (x,y) and (z,y) and the remainder are (y,y). The problem is that there are "y-3" matrices so that I cannot simply write zeros(y,y). The number of those matrices is itself an input.